# Docker-Compose Command argument is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i am new to Docker and i am starting to understand how it works. I am trying to create a `docker-compose.yml` file with `command` as argument in order to override the `CMD` command in the `Dockerfile`.
Below is my `Dockerfile` and the `docker-compose.yml` file. In this case the `CMD` in the `Dockerfile` does not exists so i expect the `command` in the `docker-compose.yml` file to run.

Dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim

# changing init 
ENV TINI_VERSION="v0.19.0"

ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# keep pip, setuptools and wheel always updated
RUN pip install -U \
    pip \
    setuptools \
    wheel

# create working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install torch torchvision --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

# copy everything in the workdir
COPY ./code .

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# define entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
# CMD [ "python", "main.py", "--model_path", "./model_e20_nf112_14122022.pt", "--input_path", "./input_images/", \
#     "--output_path", "./output_folder/", "--camera_fps", "1", "--device", "cpu", "--profiler", "True"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
  inference_container:
    image: inference
    build: 
      context: ./
    networks:
      - inference_network
    volumes:                    # link host path to docker container
      - ./data/output_images:/app/output_folder
      - ./data/profilers:/app/profiler
    environment:                # permessions for folder 
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    command: python3 main.py --model_path ./model_e20_nf112_14122022.pt --input_path ./input_images/ --output_path ./output_folder/ --camera_fps 1 --device cpu --profiler True

networks:
  # The presence of these objects is sufficient to define them
  inference_network:
```

The output of the main.py script should be different in the case the argument `--profiler` is `True` or `False`.
I build the image with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache
```

in order to start from zero the build, then i create and run the container as

```
docker-compose up
```

I started with the case `profiler = False`, then i changed its value to `True` and i execute again `docker-compose up`. However the result is the same even if in the code the change is perceived as you can see below (first print is the value of profiler input).

```
[+] Running 1/1
Container unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 Created
Attaching to unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1

unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | False
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Starting Camera Acquisition Process
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Starting Inference Process
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Adding Image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Retrieving Image for inference 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Adding Image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | No more images to acquire
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Retrieving Image for inference
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Inference Process terminated
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Images have been save in ./output_folder/
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 exited with code 0
```

```
[+] Running 1/1
Container unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 Created
Attaching to unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1

unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | True
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Starting Camera Acquisition Process
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Starting Inference Process
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Adding Image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Retrieving Image for inference 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Adding Image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | No more images to acquire
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Retrieving Image for inference
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Inference Process terminated
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 | Images have been save in ./output_folder/
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 exited with code 0
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect to be different between the two runs, other than the `True`/`False` output?  Do you have the same results running this code in a virtual environment without Docker?

Comment: I suggest you try a simpler command to verify that docker is indeed not executing the command you expect. This looks your python command may just not be behaving as you expect.

Comment: Yes indeed, there was a bug in my code. That's why it was not working. I have solved the problem now. Thanks to both of you for participating in this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. There was a bug in my code in the script main.py and that's why it was not working when i was changing the parameter in the command. Now it is all working well.

Case with profiler=False

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  Created                                                                                                                                                           0.3s
Attaching to unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Starting camera acquisition process
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Starting inference process on cpu
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Adding image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Retrieving image for inference
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Adding image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | No more images to acquire. Terminating the camera acquisition process.
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Camera acquisition process have been shut down. Performing inference on the remaining images in the queue.
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Retrieving image for inference
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Inference process on cpu terminated. The inference on 2 images has been performed.
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | The images have been saved in the folder ./output_folder/
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 exited with code 0
```

Case with profiler=True

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                         0.3s
Attaching to unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Profiler Enabled
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Starting camera acquisition process
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Starting inference process on cpu
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Adding image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Retrieving image for inference
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Adding image
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | No more images to acquire. Terminating the camera acquisition process.
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Camera acquisition process have been shut down. Performing inference on the remaining images in the queue.
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Retrieving image for inference
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | Inference process on cpu terminated. The inference on 2 images has been performed.
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | The images have been saved in the folder ./output_folder/
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |          5438 function calls (5562 primitive calls) in 0.531 seconds
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    Random listing order was used
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    List reduced from 311 to 1 due to restriction <'inference_cpu'>
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |         1    0.447    0.447   80.468   80.468 Queue_functions.py:37(inference_cpu)
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |          5438 function calls (5562 primitive calls) in 0.531 seconds
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    Random listing order was used
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    List reduced from 311 to 1 due to restriction <'TorchClasses'>
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |         2    0.004    0.002   79.007   39.504 TorchClasses.py:62(UNet.forward)
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |          5438 function calls (5562 primitive calls) in 0.531 seconds
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    Random listing order was used
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    List reduced from 311 to 1 due to restriction <'camera_acquisition'>
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  |         1    0.000    0.000    0.031    0.031 Queue_functions.py:8(camera_acquisition)
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1  | 
unibapinferencescript-inference_container-1 exited with code 0
```